# Overloading with const keyword using reference and using value

Tags: c++, reference, constants, overloading

While using const with reference in overloading compiler knows both are different. But why it doesn't differentiate if I use const with value. why the below code is not compiling.?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun(int& a)
{
    cout << "From fun(int& a)";
}
void fun(const int& a)
{
    cout << "From fun(const int& a)";
}

void fun1(int a)
{
    cout << "From fun1(int a)";
}
void fun1(const int a)
{
    cout << "From fun1(const int a)";
}

int main() {
    fun(4);
    // your code goes here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why you can't overload `fun1()` with `int` and `const int` while you can with references?

Comment: Exactly. ! @NathanOliver